how to decrease the image of imagebutton if i am using png?
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/backarrow"/>

I got this code but the image on the button appears too big that it cuts some of the photo's parts. All I want is to know if there is any way to decrease the width and height of that background?
I have tried android:scaleType="fitCenter" but it didn't work

Hi, can you also update the image. Some visual will help contributor to understand the problem. Did you try simply resizing the image on your own and then use it?

Hello, the image that i have is drawn in paint with the resolution of 256x256px. When i try to decrease the resolution it damages the quality. i have used another png that is 512x512 in simillar way and it was perfect


this is the 512x512 code that showed correctly

Hi go to the xml file named "backarrow". Have you then tried to change the measurement parameters in it? I gave the example below.
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:width="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path android:fillColor="#ffffff" android:pathData="M12.5,5A7.5,7.5 0 0,0 5,12.5A7.5,7.5 0 0,0 12.5,20A7.5,7.5 0 0,0 20,12.5A7.5,7.5 0 0,0 12.5,5M7,10H9A1,1 0 0,1 10,11V12C10,12.5 9.62,12.9 9.14,12.97L10.31,15H9.15L8,13V15H7M12,10H14V11H12V12H14V13H12V14H14V15H12A1,1 0 0,1 11,14V11A1,1 0 0,1 12,10M16,10H18V11H16V14H18V15H16A1,1 0 0,1 15,14V11A1,1 0 0,1 16,10M8,11V12H9V11" />

If the height and width here do not help you, you can try the viewport ones.

that would have worked if i used vector xml but i am using png image
